React useContext does not allow calling callbacks
In my react js application i have 2 components, in one component i have a button and in second i want to get the moment when user clicks the button. For this i created a context where i have 2 functions, one allow user using it with the button, and second one is used in another component.
Context
import React, { createContext, useContext, useRef, useMemo } from "react";

// Define context properties
const ActionsContext = createContext();

export const ActionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const triggerCallbackRef = useRef(null);

  // Function to register the callback
  const registerCallback = (callback) => {
    triggerCallbackRef.current = callback; // Store the callback
  };

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      onGetAction: () => triggerCallbackRef.current,
      onTrigerAction: registerCallback,
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <ActionsContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ActionsContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Custom hook to use the PageActions context
export const useActions = () => {
  const context = useContext(ActionsContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(" must be used within a Provider");
  }
  return context;
};



import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useActions } from "./context";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { onTrigerAction } = useActions(); // Get the register function

  return <button onClick={onTrigerAction}>click</button>;
};

export default MyComponent;


import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useActions } from "./context";

const MyOtherComponent = () => {
  const { onGetAction } = useActions();
  onGetAction(() => {
    console.log("button is cliked");
  });
  return "Hello";
};

export default MyOtherComponent;


 <ActionsProvider>
  <MyComponent />
  <MyOtherComponent />
 </ActionsProvider>

I expect to trigger the console log here
 onGetAction(() => {
    console.log("button is cliked");
  });

but nothing happens when i click. 
How to fix?

Is there a reason why you think you'd be able to pass a function to execute to onGetAction()? You don't specify that behaviour when you define it onGetAction: () => triggerCallbackRef.current

@Nick Parsons, could you help please to make possible to get the expected result?

@NickParsons How it will be correct, because i am a little blocked with this.

@Asking you have to bind a state with context api when state is changed it will automatically reflect all across the application.

@n_dev could you show please?

here I've wrote the answer please check this.

@Asking sure will share with you.

You seem to have your object properties mixed up, your onGetAction should register your callback, and then onTrigerAction should trigger the callback stored in your ref (if it's set). You currently have it the wrong way around and also need to change it so you're invoking the callback stored in current with ():
const value = useMemo(
  () => ({
    onGetAction: registerCallback,
    onTrigerAction: (...args) => triggerCallbackRef.current?.(...args),
  }),
  []
);



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.25.6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useRef, useMemo, useEffect } = React;

// Define context properties
const ActionsContext = createContext();

const ActionsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const triggerCallbackRef = useRef(null);

  // Function to register the callback
  const registerCallback = useCallback((callback) => {
    triggerCallbackRef.current = callback; // Store the callback
  }, []);

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      onGetAction: registerCallback,
      onTrigerAction: (...args) => triggerCallbackRef.current?.(...args),
    }),
    [triggerCallbackRef, registerCallback] // these are both stable so this is equivalent to having an empty dependency array
  );

  return (
    <ActionsContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ActionsContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Custom hook to use the PageActions context
const useActions = () => {
  const context = useContext(ActionsContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(" must be used within a Provider");
  }
  return context;
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { onTrigerAction } = useActions(); // Get the register function

  return <button onClick={onTrigerAction}>click</button>;
};

const MyOtherComponent = () => {
  const { onGetAction } = useActions();
  onGetAction(() => {
    console.log("button is cliked");
  });
  return "Hello";
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<ActionsProvider>
  <MyComponent />
  <MyOtherComponent />
</ActionsProvider>);
</script>



